# ArrayList User Input/Output Query

Tags: java

I am hoping for a little help or direction..I am pretty new to Java and I have just started writing (trying) ArrayList classes & testers. I am having a problem with the following example..the program runs but when I want to add another persons details I get the first name & last name request on the same line and can't figure out my mistake..any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    ArrayList <Person> details = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String fName, lName;
    int age;
    char choice = 'Y';
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
        fName = keyIn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
        lName = keyIn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
        age = keyIn.nextInt();

        details.add (new Person (fName, lName, age));

        System.out.print("Add Another Person? Y/N: ");
        choice = keyIn.next().charAt(0);        
    }
    while(choice =='Y' | choice == 'y');
        for(Person p : details) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please fix your code... your while-loop has a bracket-problem

Answer (score 1):

When you call `age = keyIn.nextInt();` it consumes the `int` but leaves the trailing new-line. So, this

```
choice = keyIn.next().charAt(0); // <-- returns immediately with '\n'.
```

Add a

```
keyIn.nextLine(); // <-- consume the \n
choice = keyIn.next().charAt(0); // <-- get the next input
```

Also, you're missing a pipe symbol in your `while` test.

```
while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my issue, apparently there is a bug in with the java scanner that means you can't scan with nextLine after scanner a nextInt. One work around was having a separate scanners for text & integers!

Answer (score 0):

First here is an example of how we can fix your code. The main alteration that I made here is using the System.out.println() static method instead of the System.out.print() method which WILL NOT generate a "new line". Here is a sample method:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{


    ArrayList<Person> myPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();//Create a person Array.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//Create your scanner object here.
    String keepAsking = "Y";
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
        String fName = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
        String lName = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        Person thisPerson = new Person(fName, lName, age);
        myPeople.add(thisPerson);
        for(Person p: myPeople) {
            System.out.println(p.getInfo());
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to let someone else enter their info (y/n)?");
        keepAsking = scan.next();

    }while(keepAsking.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    System.out.println("Thank you! Goodbye!");


}
```

In this case you need to use the "static" System.out.println() method or else you will not get a new line. You are simply using System.out.print() which will not start a new line for you and will jumble up your input. Making that slight alteration can help fix your code in this scenario. Here is your new output:

```
Enter your first name: 
Michael
Enter your last name: 
Jordan
Enter your age: 
55
First name: Michael
Last name: Jordan
Age: 55

Do you want to let someone else enter their info (y/n)?
y
Enter your first name: 
Kobe
Enter your last name: 
Bryant
Enter your age: 
41
First name: Michael
Last name: Jordan
Age: 55

First name: Kobe
Last name: Bryant
Age: 41

Do you want to let someone else enter their info (y/n)?
y
Enter your first name: 
Tom
Enter your last name: 
Brady
Enter your age: 
41
First name: Michael
Last name: Jordan
Age: 55

First name: Kobe
Last name: Bryant
Age: 41

First name: Tom
Last name: Brady
Age: 41

Do you want to let someone else enter their info (y/n)?
n
Thank you! Goodbye!
```

As you can see you get fresh "new lines" for your input now. Another tip is that instead of printing "System.out.println()" each time, you could technically use a static import and simply import the out to shorten your code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

Now you could simply do something such as:

```
out.println()
```

Instead of having to type "System" each time.